# Iphone addressbook

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I have used addressbook framework in my application.I want to allow user to edit and delete cotacts from my application.Which notification get generated when user edit the contact,also how to use delete functionality of addressbook framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use addressBook call back.

```
void ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback (
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
   ABExternalChangeCallback callback,
   void *context
);
```

My Sample - Register (After creating addressBookRef)

```
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, self);
```

My Smaple - Do Something & Unregister

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef abRef, CFDictionaryRef dicRef, void *context) {

    NSLog(@"!!!!!Address Book Changed!");

    //Do Something You Need. (Recreate addressbook or Reload UITableView data.)

    ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(abRef, addressBookChanged, context);
}
```

Delete, Insert, Modify ==> Read iOS AddressBook Refference.

Comment: How do you do this in SWIFT ?